# (Chrome on) Windows 8 complains certificate not yet valid

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, certificate

Chrome on Windows 8 complains that a server certificate is not yet valid. Chrome on Linux does not complain though, and Firefox on the same Windows 8 machine does not complain either.
The certificate is a webserver certificate I made myself, and was signed by my own (self-signed) CA. I imported the CA certificate correctly in both Chrome on Windows (which uses the Windows internal certificate store) and Chrome on Linux and Firefox on Windows (which has its own certificate store).

In Firefox on Windows and Chrome on Linux I can check the certificate for the browser and it correctly lists all the details from the certificate.
Even in Chrome on windows, Chrome lists on the certificate warning page the correct system time. If I then check the certificate (after ignoring the certificate message and continuing anyway) it lists the correct validity period as well (2 days ago until a year-2 days from now).

So I am pretty much flabbergasted. The certificate seems to be valid checking everything in it, but still Chrome does not accept it.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to do next for finding and fixing the issue?